# What does $*$ mean in equivalence relations?

Tags: proof-explanation

The notation of "$*$" started being used in my proof textbook in the section of equivalence relations and partitions yet it never once said what it means.

An example from the textbook:

Let $\mathbb{Z}^* = \mathbb{Z} - \{0\}.$ Define the relation on $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z^*}$ by, for all $a,c \in \mathbb{Z}$ and all $b,d \in \mathbb{Z}$

What does "$*$" mean?

Comment: The first sentence in the quote gives you the answer. "Let $\mathbb Z^*=\mathbb Z-\{0\}$". This means that we *define* $\mathbb Z^*$ to be $\mathbb Z-\{0\}$.

Comment: It's just a decoration which distinguishes the decorated symbol from the undecorated one.There are many similar notations: $X^*$, $X'$, $\hat{X}$, $\tilde{X}$, $\bar{X}$, etc

Comment: Exactly what it is equal to, of course: it is $\;\Bbb Z\;$ without zero. It is very usual in many contexts.

Comment: The $*$ is there just to distinguish $\mathbb Z^*$ from $\mathbb Z$. The definition of $\mathbb Z^*$ is exactly $\mathbb Z-\{0\}.$

Comment: Let $\mathbb{Z}^* = \mathbb{Z} - \{0\}.$

Comment: Thank you for the comments, I was thinking that $\mathbb {Z^*}$ meant something other then just $\mathbb Z^*=\mathbb Z-\{0\}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an algebraic context, many authors use $A^*$ to denote the set $A$ without the zero element.  In your specific example, the author uses $\mathbb Z^*$ to **denote** the set $\mathbb Z$ without $0$, i.e. $\mathbb Z-\{0\}$. So, $*$ is just used in a context of notation and does not denote any particular operation.

In a similar manner, it also common to write $\mathbb R^*$ for $\mathbb R-\{0\}$, $\mathbb C^*$ for $\mathbb C-\{0\}$, etc.

Comment: It should be noted that $A^*$ or $A^\times$ is more often used to denote the set of *invertible* elements of (a ring) $A$.

Comment: @Wojowu Very good point.

Answer (score 1):

The notation refers to all *non-zero* elementes, in your case, of the integers $\mathbb Z$. As it is defined by excluding $0$ from the integers by $\mathbb Z^*=\mathbb Z-\{0\}=\mathbb Z\setminus\{0\}$.